# Serializing an array containing different types

Tags: javascript, json, inheritance, typescript, instanceof

I have an array in typescript looking like this: 
`const baseElements: IBaseElement[]`

A `IBaseElement` contains some stuf:

```
export interface IBaseElement{
a: number;
b: string;
}
```

Two classes implements `IBaseElement`:

```
export class A implements IBaseElement{
}

export class B implements IBaseElement{
}
```

Class `A` and `B` are used in the `baseElements` array (`baseElements.push(A)....`)

When doing this, I can always use `instanceof` to find out if the element i'm working on is `A` or `B`, BUT at some point this will be serialized to JSON and persisted in a database.

So my question is this: Will I, when I get my data back from the DB, be able to distinguish the two types?

Please let me know if my question is not elaborate enough. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `A` and `B` have no additional properties other than those defined in `IBaseElement` then no, you won't be able to distinguish between the two. If that's your case then you should add a property like `className` which will have `A` or `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point if you need to create 2 new classes, it is that the JSON schema will diverge from the initial interface.

Basically what that means is that when you are going to retrieve some JSON from your DB, you will need to convert it explicitely. For example if you are using Angular + RxJS, you should end with the following

```
return http.get(this.url)
           .map(response => response.json().data as A)
```

as shown in the [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#heroes-and-http)

Comment: Thanks for your response :)